# Error 1064 For Data Domain MySQL

Tags: mysql

Creating a data domain for setting a range for the salary and bonus.

Here's the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (
Dept_ID INT (6) NOT NULL,
Dept_NAME VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
DeptHead_ID INT (6) NULL,
DeptAA VARCHAR (6), 
ParentDept_ID INT (4) NULL,
Location VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
DeptType VARCHAR (6),
Primary key (Dept_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee (
Emp_ID INT (6) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
Dept_ID INT (6) NOT NULL,   
Tax_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
Hire_Date DATE,
Birth_Date DATE,
Salary INT (6),
Bonus INT (6),
AddressInfo VARCHAR (6),  
Salary INT (6),
(salary > 0)
and (mod(salary, 10) = 0) 
and (bonus =< Salary)
PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID)
FOREIGN KEY(Dept_ID) REFERENCES Departments(Dept_ID)
);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to 
use near '(salary > 0) and 
(mod(salary, 10) =0)
and (bonus =< Salary),
PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID' at line 13
```

Constraint for the data domain and errors:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_Employee_Salary_dmn
CHECK ((salary > 0)
and 
(mod(salary, 10) = 0) 
and 
(bonus =< Salary)
);

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=< Salary))' at   line 7
```

Please let me know if I can provide additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict values within a `CREATE TABLE` statement. So these lines are invalid:

```
(salary > 0)
and (mod(salary, 10) = 0) 
and (bonus =< Salary)
```

Usually, you'd leave it up to the application to validate the data that's going into it. There are also some MySQL constructs you can use (look up [TRIGGERs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)), but I tend to shy away from these, as they're not portable. In any case, try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
Emp_ID INT (6) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR (6) NOT NULL,
Dept_ID INT (6) NOT NULL,   
Tax_ID INT (4) NOT NULL,
Country VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
Hire_Date DATE,
Birth_Date DATE,
Salary INT (6),
Bonus INT (6),
AddressInfo VARCHAR (6),  
PRIMARY KEY(Emp_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(Dept_ID) REFERENCES Departments(Dept_ID)
);
```

(You also had the Salary column in there twice...)

Comment: Ok, then the data domain must be a constraint. I put a constraint in the edit, but got a error.

Comment: I tried putting (salary > 0) and (mod(salary, 10) = 0) and (bonus =< Salary) into the Employee table as constraints, but got an error. The data domain for salary must be a constraint because I could not add while creating the table. Is there another way of creating a data domain for salary?

Comment: MySQL can only constrain _relationships_; it cannot constrain _data_. If you need to ensure that the salary is greater than zero, then this validation will need to be written into whatever language your application is being written in (Java, C, PHP, Python, etc.) MySQL does not have this feature, and cannot validate data in this way.

Comment: salary's resolution for the dataset is broken down into by $10 increments. For example, $50,040 salary, not $50,041 (which is by $1 increments). I have the constraint in the dataset, but need salary as a domain.